# How to validate dto with class-validator before passing to passportjs AuthGuard

Tags: nestjs, passport.js, nestjs-passport

How to validate dto with class-validator before passing to passport AuthGuard? I wanna use class-validator for validating incoming dto, but I see "unathorized" instead of bad request exception because pipes are being evaluated after guards in nestjs. How can I change this behaviour or I have to validate dto right in auth guard?

Comment: You probably cannot achieve this easily, unfortunately.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57069903/8935239

Answer (score 5):

You can implement your own guard. Let's see an example of a local strategy:

In the guard file validate the request body manually with the `class-validator` library:

```js
// src/auth/local-auth.guard.ts
import { ExecutionContext, HttpStatus, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { LogInUserDto } from '../users/dto/log-in-user.dto';
import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';
import { validate } from 'class-validator';

@Injectable()
export class LocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('local') {
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest<Request>();
    const response = context.switchToHttp().getResponse<Response>();

    // transform the request object to class instance
    const body = plainToClass(LogInUserDto, request.body);

    // get a list of errors
    const errors = await validate(body);

    // extract error messages from the errors array
    const errorMessages = errors.flatMap(({ constraints }) =>
      Object.values(constraints),
    );

    if (errorMessages.length > 0) {
      // return bad request if validation fails
      response.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).send({
        statusCode: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
        error: 'Bad Request',
        message: errorMessages,
      });
    }

    return super.canActivate(context) as boolean | Promise<boolean>;
  }
}
```

This is the DTO class that will be used for the validation in the guard:

```js
// src/users/dto/log-in-user.dto.ts
import { IsEmail, IsNotEmpty, IsString } from 'class-validator';

export class LogInUserDto {
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  password: string;
}
```

This is how the local strategy file looks like:

```js
// src/auth/local.strategy.ts
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
    super({ usernameField: 'email' });
  }

  async validate(email: string, password: string) {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(email, password);

    return user;
  }
}
```

This is how you can apply the local strategy to your route:

```js
// src/auth/auth.controller.ts
import { Controller, Post, UseGuards, Req } from '@nestjs/common';
import { LocalAuthGuard } from './local-auth.guard';
import { User } from '../users/entities/user.entity';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

  @UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
  @Post('/login')
  async logIn(
    @Req()
    request: {
      user: User;
    },
  ) {
    return await this.authService.logIn(request.user);
  }
}
```

You can check out [the official nestJS docs about the passport library](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/passport#extending-guards) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very in NestJS way, but probably the single option to use is validate DTO inside strategy, that your guard is using:

```
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Strategy } from 'passport-strategy';
import { validate } from 'class-validator';
import { BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common'; 

class YourStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    authenticate(req, options) {
        const errors = validate(req.body);

        if (errors) {
            throw new BadRequestException({ errors });
        }

        super.authenticate(req, options);
    }
}
```